# How to remove leafs from a binary tree represented with list of lists?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nested-lists

I have a binary tree represented with nested lists:
[[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]

And I want to write a function which removes the leafs (the empty lists) from it with recursion.

I tried with this but it doesn't even run. Could someone help me how to start?

```
def removeLeaf(tree):
    for i in tree:
        if type(tree[i]) is list:
            return removeLeaf(tree[i])
        elif tree[i] == []:
            tree.pop(i)
            return removeLeaf(tree)
```

> input:
>
> [[[[], []], [[], []]], [[], [], []]]
>
> output:
>
> [[[], []], []]

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call resursion in the first part of if, because you are removing the empty list that is a leaf. Also the for sentence must be changed. 
Here's the code:

```
def removeLeafs(tree):
    for i in range(0,len(tree)-1):
        if len(tree[i]) == 0:
            tree.pop(i)
        else
            removeLeafs(tree[i])
```

Comment: I've got this error with your code: IndexError: list index out of range